# Python multipage PDF to CSV

Tags: python

I need to move data from pdf to table and this script does it almost correctly. The only problem is that each page saves to a separate file. How can I do it so that everything is in one file?

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

file = "O:\Files to Import\Millwood - DEV\LIST.PDF"
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file,pages='all')
tables[0].to_csv("O:\Files to Import\Millwood - DEV\FOOOO.csv")
tables[1].to_csv("O:\Files to Import\Millwood - DEV\FOOO1.csv")
```

Comment: Make sure you're using raw string literals for the paths, or use `pathlib.Path` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `for table in tables:`
I think about two solutions:

1. Collect tables in Pandas DataFrame and finish export to csv. [Use .append](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)
2. Remove first row in each csv and merge csv (maybe this is bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found and it works perfect for me, so I have one csv file.

```
import tabula 
tabula.convertinto("file path", "output.csv", outputformat="csv", pages="all")
```